# How can you track or be notified of changes to GitHub wikis?

Tags: github, gollum-wiki

Are there service hooks for [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) wiki repositories? Is there some other mechanism that GitHub provides for me to track wiki edits?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Push approach:** Within the [GitHub API documentation](http://developer.github.com/v3/), you can find documentation about setting up [service hooks](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/) which can be triggered for one or more events. The `gollum` event is especially raised any time a wiki page is updated.

**JSON-based pull approach:** You can also leverage the [Events HTTP API](http://developer.github.com/v3/events/) to retrieve a JSON formated output of what happens on GitHub, then apply some filtering in order to isolate the events of type `GollumEvent`.

Below a quick jQuery-based sample

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gollum events</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/repos/holman/spark/events?callback=?', function(data) {

                    var list = $('#gollum-events');

                    $.each(data.data, function(key, val) {
                        if (val.type == "GollumEvent") {
                            $.each(val.payload.pages, function(key2, val2) {
                                list.append('<li id="' + key + '.' + key2 + '"><a href="' + val2.html_url + '">' + val2.page_name + '</a> [' + val.actor.login + ' @ ' + val.created_at + ']</li>');
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="gollum-events"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Atom based pull approach:** Last but not least, you can subscribe to the wiki changes atom feed. Go to the GitHub Wiki section of the repository, select the `Pages` sub tab, hover onto the orange icon, copy the link and paste into your favorite RSS reader.

[image: Subscribe to changes]

### Update:

It looks like the RSS feed icon is no longer displayed for a wiki.

However, you can still build the URL by yourself

- **Syntax:** `https://github.com/:user/:repository/wiki.atom`
- **Example:** ***https://github.com/holman/spark/wiki.atom***

Comment: The push approach is what I was looking for, thanks.  Next request would be some nice way to render the diffs for edits - similar to what you can see using the normal github ui.

Comment: Is it still possible to get an Atom feed of a repo's recent wiki edits? I don't see an RSS icon at https://github.com/holman/spark/wiki/_pages

Comment: @PhilipDurbin I've updated the answer with the syntax to guess by yourself the rss feed link.

Answer (score 3):

I set up a Jenkins job to pull our GitHub wiki from https://github.com/IQSS/dvn.wiki.git with a build trigger of @daily. In a build step, I'm executing a shell command like this to email us:

> echo "The DVN wiki on GitHub has been updated. Please check for new content at https://github.com/IQSS/dvn/wiki/_history" | mail -s "[dvn-wiki-notifications] update detected" dvn@example.com

Here's the job if anyone cares to see: https://build.hmdc.harvard.edu:8443/job/dvn-wiki-notifications/